# Woocommerce checkout decrease spaces between fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommmerce store with a checkout where the fields have a lot of space between them. I would like to decrease the space through CSS. Can't find any information about this and I've tried many different codes found online, but they were too I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use as specific a selector as possible.

```
.woocommerce form p.form-row{
    margin: 0 0 5px;
}
.woocommerce form p.form-row label{
    margin: 0 0 5px;
}
```

The last value is top and bottom margin, so smaller = closer together.

Comment: That increases or decreases the horizontaly. Not between fields. At least it's what I'm getting :(

Comment: Can you provide a link, html or example image?

Comment: It works. I had to put negative 30px to make it work